# Pass HTML body via javascript to div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a webpage (or really just a simple document for the sole purpose of writing a help file for another project). I have an HTML document which splits to document in 2 panes, i.e.

```
<body onload="addEvents();">

    <div class="split left">
    </div>

    <div class="split right">
        <div id="description_viewer">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

My "split left" div contains the tree structure of simple text. A typical tree may contain  multiple level of list items, with the final level containing a list item with a dd tag that contains text information in the form of headers and paragraphs i.e.

```
        <ul id="LinkedList1" class="LinkedList">
            <li>MyParent
                <ul>
                    <li>MyFirstChild    
                        <ul>
                            <li>MyChildofFirstChild
                                <dd>This contains a description of myChildofFirstChild
                                    <h2>MainHead</h2>
                                        <h3>SubHeader</h3>
                                            <p>Description</p>
                                            <p>Description</p>
                                        <h3>SubHeader</h3>
                                        <h3>SubHeader</h3>
                                            <h4>SubSubHeader</h4>
                                            <h4>SubSubHeader</h4>
                                                <p>Description</p>
                                </dd>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

My script file allows for the user to open or close list items in the tree, with the intention when the user clicks a list item that contains a dd tag the html code insider the dd tag is displayed in the right panel (i.e div "split right").

I also need to keep the header tags etc for formatting.

To date I have only been able to display the text [object HTMLCollection].

I gather I need to use .map.call but I have no html/javascript knowledge.

Thanks,

Comment: What Javascript have you tried so far?

Comment: Array.map implies you have some data in a javascript array that somehow matters to your question.

Comment: my first attempt was using document.getElementById("description_viewer").innerHTML=cSubDescription where cSubDescription = document.getElementById("dd")

Comment: There are pre-written widget sets for creating expanding hierarchies. I suggest you use one of them instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: I have the tree hierarchy working fine, I only wish to have a view pane on the right side to display the html in the dd tag